Range of a rational function.
I wanted to know conditions on coefficients for range of y to be $R$, the set of real numbers
$$y=\frac{a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}..(1)$$
(Obviously, domain of the function does not include roots of the dinominator polynomial)
So, $$x^2(a_2y-a_1)+x(b_2y-b_1)+c_2y-c_1=0$$
Since for each y there exists a x satisfying equation (1), we can put its discriminant to be non negative.
This is on the assumption that $y≠\frac{a_1}{a_2}$.
Now, $D_1≥0$ gives,
$$y^2(b_2^2-4a_2c_2)+y(4a_1c_2+4a_2c_1-2b_1b_2)+b_1^2-4a_1c_1≥0$$
$$\implies D_2≤0$$and$$\implies b_2^2-4a_2c_2>0$$
I further simplified the discriminant condition into
$$(a_1c_2-a_2c_1)^2≤(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)(b_1c_2-b_2c_1)$$
(if we put $y=a_1/a_2$ , we get a specific value of x in terms of the coeficients)
Apparantly , I have made wrong conclusions somewhere because if $D_2≥0$ follows expressions in numerator and denominator will have a common roots and y (rational function) will reduce to something like $\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$
We do not want this since range of y is to be all real numbers , $R$.

Please provide the right conditions and their derivation also point the mistake in mine. Thank You.

Here is a sufficient condition.
Suppose the denominator has two distinct real roots $r_1 < r_2$, and the numerator has two real roots $s_1 < s_2$ with one of $s_1$ and $s_2$  between $r_1$ and $r_2$.  Your function (call it $f(y)$) is continuous for $r_1 < y < r_2$, with the denominator having constant sign there while the numerator changes sign once in that interval.  Therefore one of $\lim_{y \to r_1+} f(y)$ and $\lim_{y \to r_2-} f(y)$ is $+\infty$  and the other is $-\infty$, and by the Intermediate Value Theorem the range is all of $\mathbb R$.

But ,if possible, I'd like to have conditions on coefficients since factoring a quadratic can be tedious and sometimes not possible in the reals.

For numerator and denominator to both have two real roots you want the discriminants $b_i^2 - 4 a_i c_i > 0$ for $i = 1$ and $2$.  The roots can then be expressed in the usual way with the quadratic formula. It may be tedious, but that's life.
